# jQuery - using .prepend()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using jQuery in my project, where I got some problems with .prepend(). Please go to http://qlimp.com and login using this username/password: dummy/dummy Then click the link **Go to Information settings**. Click the **add service** button -> then click **facebook icon** -> just click **Add button**

You will see the blue **facebook tag**. When you do that process once again, then you will see **three** facebook tags(prepending two tags at once) instead of **two**. It's like prepending twice the no. of previous tags. Why is it so?

Here is the jQuery code:

```
$("#facebook").click(function(){
    $("#facebook-info").fadeIn("slow");
    $("#facebook-button").click(function(){
        a = a+1;
        $("#service-sets").prepend('<div class="tag" id="'+a+'"><span class="blue-tag">Facebook<span class="delete-tag"><i class="icon-cancel-circle-1" id="facebook-del"></i></span></span></div>');
    });
});

$("#service-sets").on('click', '#facebook-del', function() {
    $("#facebook-tag").remove();
});
```

HTML

```
<div id="service-sets">
</div>
```

I just checked in jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/YVZH5/ with the sample code and it is working(prepending one tag at once). Could anyone tell me the mistake I've done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Use only one `click` event. You are doing it for the parent and child element.

```
$("#facebook-button").click(function(){
    $("#facebook-info").fadeIn("slow");   
        a = a+1;
        $("#service-sets").prepend('<div class="tag" id="'+a+'"><span class="blue-tag">Facebook<span class="delete-tag"><i class="icon-cancel-circle-1" id="facebook-del"></i></span></span></div>');      
});
```

And make sure, If you have the click event bounded to the parent and child div, when you click on child div you are stopping the parent events event. you may use `stopPropagation` to stop the bubbling event execution.

Comment: But I need that `facebook-button` click event.

Comment: then use that only instead of facebook.

Comment: The double .click seems to be causing issues.